# Can I root my Samsung J7?

Tags: root-access, 7.0-nougat

I need to know if I can root my Samsung J7 Verizon variant. 
The android version is 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but for many Samsung devices, [CF-Auto-Root](http://cfautoroot.com/) will work. It worked for mine.

Comment: A link and detailed instructions would be welcome here per site standards. [Here](https://download.chainfire.eu/1168/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-j7popltevzw-j7popltevzw-smj727v.zip)'s the download for the particular model SM-J727V with build number `NRD90M.J727VVRU1AQF3`.